# How to generate a list of permutations with a constraint on index values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create permutation of a given list with a constraint such that,

```
given input sequence=(x_0, x_1, x_2,..) and an integer k, the output sequence=(x_perm(0), x_perm(1), x_perm(2),..) with perm(i)< i+k. 

For example for k=2 that means;

   x_perm(0) is either x_0 or x_1

   x_perm(1) is either x_0, x_1 or x_2

Another example for input=[3,4,5] and k=2 is:

output=[4,3,5] is a valid permutation, but [5,4,3] is not since x_perm(0) cannot be x_2.
```

```py
def spec_perm(iterable, k):
    import random
    perm=[0]*len(iterable)
    for i in range (0,len(iterable)):
        perm[i]=random.choice(iterable[0:k+i])
    return perm
```

I have tried this code, but random choice includes repetitions so it does not generate the desired results.

In the end, I need to get all valid permutations.

Comment: I dont really understand what exactly you want, but have you tried itertools.permutations ? https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: Yes I have tried but, but I couldn't include the rule perm(i)< i+k within this setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is almost complete. It just needs a little touch. You said random module includes repetitions, so it does not generate your desired results. Why not use a list of *possible indexes* and *used indexes*. So that you can generate your possible indexes everytime, and remove the used ones.

```
def spec_perm(iterable, k):
    import random
    perm=[0]*len(iterable)
    used_index = [] #Initiate the list of used indexes.
    for i in range (0,len(iterable)):
        #Declare the possible range.
        if i+k < len(iterable):
            index_range = list(range(0, i+k))
        else:
            index_range = list(range(0, len(iterable)))
        #Get rid of the used indexes by using a list comprehension. 
        possible_index = [idx for idx in index_range if idx not in used_index] 
        #Make your random index choice AND assign it to a variable 
        #so that you can append it to used_index list later.
        random_index = random.choice(possible_index) 
        perm[i]=iterable[random_index]
        #Update the used indexes by appending the random index choice to the list.
        used_index.append(random_index) 


    return perm
```

Hope this helps. Kolay gelsin:)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really great, but we need one more touch as I need to be  sure that in `index_range = list(range(0, i+k))` i+k should not be bigger than len(iterable). teşekkürler:)

Comment: @GözdeFiliz Yeah, I've missed that. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are interested in.
Python provide direct methods to find permutations. These methods are present in itertools package.

Import itertools package to implement permutations method in python. This method takes a list as an input and return an object list of tuples.

```
# import itertools
from itertools import permutations 

# Get all permutations of ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
perm = permutations(['a', 'b', 'c']) 

# Print the obtained permutations 
for i in list(perm): 
    print i
```

Let's say you want to get permutations of length n (say n = 2) then,all you have to do is,

```
#change
perm = permutations(['a', 'b', 'c']) 

#to
perm = permutations(['a', 'b', 'c'],2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I couldn't find a way to add the rule perm(i)< i+k within this code.